# error C2614: illegal member initialization: 'b' is not a base or member

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++14

How do I get this code to compile?

```
struct A
{
    A() : b{}, c{} {}
    ~A() {}
    union tag
    {
        const std::shared_ptr<int>  b;
        const std::shared_ptr<int>  c;
    }   m_dfs;  
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

I am getting the following error from the VS2017 compiler:

```
warning C4624: 'A::tag': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
error C2614: 'A': illegal member initialization: 'b' is not a base or member
error C2614: 'A': illegal member initialization: 'c' is not a base or member
```

I assume I have similar issues in gcc 7.

Update based on comments. This compiles

```
struct A
{
    A() : m_dfs{} {}
    ~A() {}
    union tag
    {
        const std::shared_ptr<int>  b;
        const std::shared_ptr<int>  c;
        ~tag() {};
    }   m_dfs;  
};

int main()
{
    A a;
}
```

Comment: Unions containing complex non-trivial objects do have some limitations. You might also need to implement constructors and destructors for the union. Please see e.g. [this `union` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) for more information.

Comment: As for the errors, the compiler is correct (of course). You don't have any members `A::b` or `A::c`. You do have a member `A::m_dfs` though.